# Exclamation mark missing in facebook API name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

My facebook api name contains exclamation mark (`!`). Whenever I share something on facebook through the API, the post contains the API name, but it removes the exclamation mark. Does anyone have any idea about how to display `!`.

**EDIT 1:** Please see below image to get better idea of my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The 'via' link's text on Facebook.com in News Feed or on Timeline isn't populated by anything in your IOS App's code or ShareKit configuration; it's from the App's basic settings page,  accessible at https://developers.facebook.com/apps when logged in as an admin of the app

For example, here's my app settings for a test app:

[image: App settings page]

And how a post appears:

[image: sample post]

If i change the app name:

[image: App settings page after change]

It appears with the !

[image: Sample post after change]

Comment: OK, based on OP's edit, i'm not 100% sure this is the answer - i'm not sure what part of the Facebook API ShareKit is calling to create the 'Get FondlyYours' text in the OP's screenshot, if anyone knows, i may have a suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I've tried with "& #33;" and "& #x21;" (without space and without quotes) and it's working, can you try again?

**EDIT**

---

I think that the problem is in the method: `- (BOOL)send` from the class `SHKFacebook.m`. Make sure that the SHKMyAppName or your SHKItem info is encoding with SHKEncode and not with SHKEncodeURL

Comment: i tried your suggestion And then i tried this http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0021/index.htm  But still not working.

Comment: Are you using the Facebook API or another library over this?

Comment: Yes i am using Facebook API via Sharekit . And i am assigning #define SHKMyAppName  @"ABC!" But i am not getting (!) in post on facebook wall.

Comment: If i use '& #33;' , it displays '%26%2333;' and if i use '& #x21;', it displays '%26%23x21;'

Comment: Which version of ShareKit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using '\' before the explanation mark ie:

```
APIKEY = "348geIb\!rgreg"
```